# Need some help with some homework problems

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

A = {x ∈ R: 1 < x < 5} 
B = {∅} 
C = {4, 5, 9, 10}

Determine whether each of these is true or false based on the given above.

1) π ⊂ A 
2) {π} ⊂ A 
3) B ⊆ C

What I think:
1) False, because π is an element of A so there is a real number x that would equal π in the set A. Therefore π cannot be a proper subset of A. 
2) False, because A is not a set containing another set. 
3) (This one I'm not so sure. Is a set containing an empty set a subset of a non-empty set?)

Comment: Do you know the definition of being a subset?

Comment: The null set is a subset of any set.

Comment: Before you can get any further, you need to review what the definition of a subset is. Based on your explanations it looks like you don’t understand the definition. There are quite a few posts in here too that deal with helping people understand this.  You should read some of those posts and you will probably understand more.

Comment: @TyJensen Your comment is true but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Correct, it is indeed false, though your wording makes it a bit vague. Let's make it a little more simple: the relation of $\in$ (i.e. "an element of") is not the same as $\subset$ (i.e. "a subset of"). $\pi \in A$ (since $3 < \pi < 4$), but it represents only a single element, and not a set.
2. You're wrong in this respect. If $P \subset Q$, then for all $p \in P$ it follows that $p \in Q$ as well. Is $\{ \pi \} \subset A$? For all elements of your singleton set, i.e. $\pi$, do they appear in $A$? Since $\pi \in A$, it follows $\{ \pi \} \subset A$.
3. The empty set is a subset of every set, true, but $\emptyset \ne \{ \emptyset \}$. One of these has no elements in it, and the other is a set containing a set (whether the contained set is empty doesn't matter). So, we refer again to the definition. For all elements of $B$, namely $\emptyset$, is $\emptyset \in C$? Obviously not, since the elements of $C$ are $4,5,9,10$, none of which is the empty set.

Answer (score 0):

(1.) Makes no sense to me as $\pi$ is not a set, and therefore can never be a subset.  Let's say its false.

(2.) A contains all *real* numbers (of which $\pi$ is one) between $1$ and $5$. Because $\pi$ is certainly between $3$ and $4$, $\pi$ is an *element* of $A$. Now $\{\pi\}$ is a set which contains only $\pi$. So if $x \in A$ then $x=\pi$. well then clearly $x \in A$.

(3.) This is tricky.  It's tempting to say true because the empty set is always a subset of every set.  However, this is not what we have.  The object in $B$ is ''the set containing the empty set''. So if $x \in B$ then $x$ is the empty set. The empty set is not an element of $C$ ($C$'s elements are numbers, not sets). This is false.